# Getting over bid-ask bounce

Tags: autoregressive, lstm

High-frequency financial data is subject to *bid-ask bounce*.

**Description :** Unlike traditional data based on just closing prices, tick data carry additional supply-and-demand information in the form of bid and ask prices and offering sizes.

As a researcher, it can be an advantage because bid and ask quotes can carry valuable information about impending market moves.

However, bid and ask quotes are separated by a spread. Continuous movement from bid to ask and back introduces a jump process, difficult to deal with through many conventional models.

I am actually working on high-frequency trading project. At the beginning, I wanted to predict the price movement, but because the price is non-stationary and other reasons, it made the problem harder than I was expected. Now, instead of dealing with the price, I deal with the log-returns on the midprice (mean between the best bid and best ask) and the features.

**Why am I talking of features?**

For autoregressive problem, it is well known that RNN-LSTM perform pretty well on a time-series forecasting problem. As the midprices as well as the features are not stationary, then I applied the log-returns on all of them. I think it will be easier to approach the solution of my problem.

However, I think I face the problem of bid-ask bounce. How can I get over that setback? Does the log on the midprice is sufficient to face that problem?